# Routing default 404 not working

Tags: angular, angular-universal

When I go to  www.myweb.com/something the web will display the message:

```
{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "No Content"
}
```

Here is my app.routes:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'account', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'account', component: Account },
  { path: 'followers', component: Followers },
  { path: 'explore/:id', component: Explore },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'account' },
  ];
```

Im using angular universal, so I have another file called server.ts whit this code:

```
// Routes with html5pushstate
// ensure routes match client-side-app
app.get('/', ngApp);
app.get('/followers', ngApp);
app.get('/followers/*', ngApp);
app.get('/account', ngApp);
app.get('/account/*', ngApp);
app.get('/explore', ngApp);
app.get('/explore/*', ngApp);
```

Where is the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below,

```
 // notice the slash in front of account navigation
 { path: '**', redirectTo: '/account' }
```

It makes navigation absolute if the path does not match.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) :(